# Cocos2dx-android-Assert Error :ccArray.cpp function:ccArrayAppendObject line:120

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

Assert Error :ccArray.cpp function:ccArrayAppendObject line:120

this is the error when i am trying to execute a frame animation using this code :

```
CCArray *frames= CCArray::create();

for(int i=0 ; i<=21 ; i++)
{
        CCString *frame=CCString::createWithFormat("mypong%04d.png",i);
        frames->addObject(CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(frame->getCString()));
    }
    sprite->runAction(CCAnimate::create(CCAnimation::create(frames,.01)));
}
```

its under TouchesBegan method.Anyone knows what i am doing wrong here ?

NOTE: i am on win7 64-bit ,cocos2dx 2.0.1, ndk r8b

Comment: check that CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(frame->getCString()) always returns a non-nil object, and where it returns nil, find out why

Comment: thanks sire ..i checked my spritesheet and it contained 5 black images !!

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no `CCSpriteFrame` named `mypong%04d.png` in `CCSpriteFrameCache`. You might have ran `CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->removeUnusedSpriteFrames()` or something simillar before.

Or you are missing .png files in your project folder so they failed to add into `CCSpriteFrameCache`

Answer (score 0):

okay the problem was that my spritesheet got corrupted or something weird happened with it..it does not contain images from frame 10 to 15 ...dont know what happened to it...there are five black images in the spritesheet !!